# Styling border of input elements on change event

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces, border, jsf-2.2

I use PrimeFaces as JSF component library and try to implement a basic and mechanism that allows the user to see which input elements on the page have been changed. The idea is to hook to the onchange event and to set a different border color with Javascript as follows:

```
function setChangedStyle(element) {
    PrimeFaces.info('Trying to set border on element ' + element);
    var input = document.getElementById(element.id);
    if (input != undefined) {
        var borderStyle = "1px solid #eab069";
        input.style.border = borderStyle;
        PrimeFaces.info('Set border style to ' + borderStyle);
    } else {
        PrimeFaces.info('Element is undefinded');
    }
}
```

It works fine on input elements such as  fields.

```
<p:inputText id="justAnIdForAField" onchange="setChangedStyle(this)" value="#{someBean.aField}" />
```

Here's the rendered output of the elements:

- `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox/>`

  ```
      <div id="someForm:someBooleanInput" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
          <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
              <input id="someForm:someBooleanInput_input"
                  name="someForm:someBooleanInput_input" type="checkbox"
                  onchange="setChangedStyle(this);" />
          </div>
          <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
              <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span>
          </div>
      </div>
  ```
- `<p:selectOneMenu/>`

  ```
   <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
      <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><label
          id="someForm:j_idt68" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"
          for="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_focus">SelectOne Input</label></td>
      <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell"><div
              id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput"
              class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
      <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
          <input id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_focus"
              name="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_focus" type="text"
              autocomplete="off" />
      </div>
      <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
          <select id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_input"
              name="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_input" tabindex="-1"
              onchange="setChangedStyle(this);">
              <option value="" selected="selected">One</option>
              <option value="" selected="selected">Two</option>
              <option value="" selected="selected">Three</option>
          </select>
      </div>
      <label id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_label"
          class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">&nbsp;</label>
      <div
          class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
          <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span>
      </div>
      <div id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_panel"
          class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow">
          <div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height: auto">
              <ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
                  <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="One">One</li>
                  <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Two">Two</li>
                  <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Three">Three</li>
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>
      </div>
          <script id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("SelectOneMenu","widget_someForm_someSelectMenuInput",{id:"someForm:someSelectMenuInput",widgetVar:"widget_someForm_someSelectMenuInput"});});</script></td>
  </tr>
  ```
- `<p:calendar/>`

  ```
      <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
      <span id="someForm:someCalendarInput">
      <input id="someForm:someCalendarInput_input" name="someForm:someCalendarInput_input" type="text"
              class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onchange="setChangedStyle(this)" />
      </span>
  ```

And here's the HTML output of the whole page:

```
    <table id="someForm:j_idt65" class="ui-panelgrid ui-widget" role="grid">
<tbody>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
            <label id="someForm:j_idt66" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"
                for="someForm:someInput">Input</label>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
            <input id="someForm:someInput" name="someForm:someInput" type="text"
                onchange="setChangedStyle(this)" class="ui-inputfield ui-inputtext ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" />
                <script id="someForm:someInput_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("InputText","widget_someForm_someInput",{id:"someForm:someInput",widgetVar:"widget_someForm_someInput"});</script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
            <label id="someForm:j_idt67" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"
                for="someForm:someBooleanInput_input">Boolean Input</label>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
            <div id="someForm:someBooleanInput" class="ui-chkbox ui-widget">
                <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                    <input id="someForm:someBooleanInput_input" name="someForm:someBooleanInput_input" type="checkbox" onchange="setChangedStyle(this);" />
                </div>
                <div class="ui-chkbox-box ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
                    <span class="ui-chkbox-icon ui-icon ui-icon-blank ui-c"></span>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <script id="someForm:someBooleanInput_s" type="text/javascript">PrimeFaces.cw("SelectBooleanCheckbox","widget_someForm_someBooleanInput",{id:"someForm:someBooleanInput",widgetVar:"widget_someForm_someBooleanInput"});</script>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
            <label id="someForm:j_idt68" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"
                for="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_focus">SelectOne Input</label>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
        <div id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
            <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <input id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_focus" name="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
                <select id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_input" name="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_input" tabindex="-1" onchange="setChangedStyle(this);">
                    <option value="" selected="selected">One</option>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Two</option>
                    <option value="" selected="selected">Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <label id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">&nbsp;</label>
            <div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right">
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow">
                <div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height: auto">
                    <ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset">
                        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="One">One</li>
                        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Two">Two</li>
                        <li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Three">Three</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <script id="someForm:someSelectMenuInput_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("SelectOneMenu","widget_someForm_someSelectMenuInput",{id:"someForm:someSelectMenuInput",widgetVar:"widget_someForm_someSelectMenuInput"});});</script></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="ui-widget-content" role="row">
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
            <label id="someForm:j_idt72" class="ui-outputlabel ui-widget"
                for="someForm:someCalendarInput_input">Calendar Input</label>
        </td>
        <td role="gridcell" class="ui-panelgrid-cell">
            <span id="someForm:someCalendarInput">
                <input id="someForm:someCalendarInput_input" name="someForm:someCalendarInput_input" type="text" class="ui-inputfield ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onchange="setChangedStyle(this)" />
            </span> 
            <script id="someForm:someCalendarInput_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Calendar","widget_someForm_someCalendarInput",{id:"someForm:someCalendarInput",widgetVar:"widget_someForm_someCalendarInput",popup:true,locale:"de",dateFormat:"dd.mm.y",showOn:"button"});});</script>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Despite all, I am struggling with other components to get everything working.

- `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox/>` and `<p:selectOneMenu/>`: The onchange event seems to be fired, but there are no visible changes to the border style.
- `<p:calendar/>`: The onchange event does not seem to be fired (no log entries), so no changes at all.

I never run into the `else`-statement that logs 'Element is undefined'.

Could anybody please let me know if I am doing something wrong and where I need to start tuning.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Look at the generated xhtml of the two selects.  The html inputs are hidden helpers. You have to put your border on some other html element

Comment: Can you look what is the genetated html code for the select elements, and add it to the question?

Comment: need to find out the event for generated element  like for calender control or try directly giving border to elements to see whether it works

Comment: @Kukeltje: Thanks for the hint. I have just pasted the generated HTML code. Should have thought of that as well.
@Ram Tobolski: I have added the generated HTML code as you requested.
@Nadeemmnn Mohd: According to the PrimeFaces user guide, every control in question seems to have the `onchange` event

Comment: For the selectOneMenu you miss the wrapping element with the ui-widget class

Comment: @Kukeltje: added the missing element

Comment: That is ui-widget-content, not ui-widget.  But did you also change the javascript to add the border to the correct html element?

Comment: @Kukeltje: Indeed. No, I did not change the javascript as it turned out that this is the "real" question. Is it true that I need to set the border on the `someForm:someSelectMenuInput_panel`? How do I achieve this in the javascript function? Some sort of `if (input /*is of type 'select'*/) { // search for the correct panel to set the border and set the border style }`

Comment: Wel... If you have a dom element, you can use plain javascript dom access to get to parents and higher.  But it is maybe easier to use jquery selectors to get to the correct element.  The `this.closest('.ui-widget')` selector is what comes to mind.

Answer (score 0):

The following Javascript function goes through the DOM tree and manipulates the borders of the respective input elements.

The script works with PrimeFaces 5.1, JSF 2.2. (Mojarra) on Wildfly 8.2.

```
/**
* Changes the border color of an input element. 
* 
* @param element
*/
function setChangedStyle(element) {
var borderStyle = "1px solid #eab069";

PrimeFaces.info('Element calling this function ' + element);
var input = document.getElementById(element.id);

if (input != undefined) {
    if (input.getAttributeNode("type") != undefined) {
        PrimeFaces.info('TYPE ' + input.getAttributeNode("type").value);

        var inputType = input.getAttributeNode("type").value;
        if (inputType == 'text') {
            // Set border of inputText
            input.style.border = borderStyle;

        } else if (inputType == 'checkbox') {
            // If we deal with a checkbox, we expect the following:
            // the input element itself is located in a hidden div that is
            // located in a parent div. The parent div has two child
            // elements. 
            // The border needs to be set on the span element that resides
            // inside the div next to the hidden div.

            // Set border of checkbox
            input.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes.item(1).childNodes.item(0).style.border = borderStyle;
        } else {
            PrimeFaces.info('Unhandled input type');
        }
    } else {
        // Different input component
        if ("ui-selectonemenu".indexOf(input.parentNode.parentNode.getAttributeNode("class").value)) {
            // Set border of the selectOneMenu
            input.parentNode.parentNode.style.border = borderStyle;
        } else {
            PrimeFaces.info('Unhandled input type');
        }
    }
} else {
    PrimeFaces.info('Element is undefinded');
}
```